# Very basic MySQL code not working

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I'm struggling with some very basic MySQL code, so I'm clearly misunderstanding something very fundamental. This super simple code is a good example:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table (count int);
INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES((1),(2),(3));
SELECT * FROM temp_table;
```

This returns:

```
11 errors were found during analysis.

A comma or a closing bracket was expected (near "1" at position 31)
Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 32)
Unexpected token. (near "," at position 33)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 34)
Unexpected token. (near "2" at position 35)
Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 36)
Unexpected token. (near "," at position 37)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 38)
Unexpected token. (near "3" at position 39)
Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 40)
Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 41)
```

It works just fine if I only do `INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES(1);` But it seems to take issue with me using parentheses, so I can't seem to insert multiple values.

If I do `INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES(1,2,3);` It returns `#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

And I'm running into issues like this again and again with various MySQL code examples that I'm finding in various sources, including StackOverflow. So I'm not sure what I'm missing.

In my hosts control panel, I can see that I'm running MariaDB 5.3 and in phpMyAdmin (4.5.2), I can see that I'm running MySQL 5.7.9.

And yet I run into issues running code that comes directly from [MariaDB's website](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/create-table/).

Would you mind (gently) cluing me in? I'm sure this must be basic, and I'm willing to learn. I just don't know what the problem is, and until I learn these fundamentals, I'm just going to be spinning my wheels.

Comment: That outdated version of phpMyAdmin has some issues with the linter and parser, which is showing some improper warnings/errors here. Your code still needs fixup as described elsewhere, but you should upgrade your phpMyAdmin to fix the parser problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove wrapping ()

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table (count int);
INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES(1),(2),(3);
SELECT * FROM temp_table;
```

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful to know in this example. I guess part of what's throwing me is that phpmyadmin is displaying errors in the editor, but when I run the code, it works just fine. So why would it be showing an error if there isn't really an issue? Doesn't seem very helpful.

Another example is 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test2 SELECT * FROM test;' In phpmyadmin, it underlines 'select' in red and complains about 'An opening bracket was expected', but yet when I run the code, it works just fine.

Comment: The code you provided generate error in all IDE .. i use Toad and (with other terms) raise errror too) .. could be the ide processing of myphpadmin do a wrong parsing analisys ..

Comment: I actually just downloaded Toad the other day, but I didn't see much use in it. I'll have to reinstall it and give it another shot if it'll be more helpful than the editor in phpMyadmin. Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on @scaisEdge note, when you write insert query with multiple values, you cannot group all values together.

```
 //Wrong
 INSERT INTO temp_table values ((val1),(val2),(val3));
```

You should do the following instead:

```
//Right
INSERT INTO temp_table values (val1), (val2), (val3);
```

Hence your query should be:

```
INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES(1),(2),(3);
```

Hope this explains, enjoy!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Part of what throws me is why some MySQL code works for some people (such as the person that this example came from: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3844811/Make-Your-MySQL-Queries-More-Efficient-with-Temporary-Tables.htm) and not for others (me). I'm assuming it's related to which version of MySQL you're running, but I'm not sure how to get acquainted with all the various minute differences. Trial and error?

Comment: @Tim, the link http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3844811/Make-Your-MySQL-Queries-More-Efficient-with-Temporary-Tables.htm, appears to have an incorrect syntax/typo. Check out the api docs here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html, these clearly suggest/show you cannot group values together.